# How To run unit tests with mocha on Webstorm?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, webstorm

I'm trying to run mocha tests directly on the WebStorm IDE but without any success.

This is my jsTestDriver.conf file:

```
server: http://localhost:4224

load:
  - node_modules/mocha/mocha.js
  - node_modules/chai/chai.js
  - node_modules/requirejs/require.js
  - mocha-jstd-adapter/src/MochaAdapter.js
  - routes/*.js

test:
  - test/*.js

timeout: 90
```

Now I'm taking a look at the buster-format module that works correctly. Any help is appreciated (I'll post the solution if I did it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is that it's not possible currently.

As stated on the documentation, you can only:

- do tests with mocha and other frameworks for front-end javascript with coverage and everything using JSTestDriver or Karma;
- do tests with ONLY nodeunit for node.js, so NOT mocha or something else, but you cannot have the coverage with nodeunit either.

Hopefully this will option will be implemented soon.

It's possible to do test with mocha but without code-coverage.

Answer (score 2):

Mocha support will be included in WebStorm 7.0.2. You can try the RC build available at http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+7+EAP